# SSRS Hidden Property Causing Issue with Rows that should not be hidden

Tags: reporting-services

My report has 3 groups (Team, AgentID, Agent Name). We have agents that are on more than one team during a period of time. The report returns all sales and cancellations, so we can calcuate a cancel %. When rendering the report, we suppress the sales, and only show detail row data for the cancels. If an agent is on one team and has cancels they would have a cancel% and detail rows, but if on thier second team they had no cancles then thier cancel % would be 0.00 %, and nothing should show for them.

I applied hidden expression on the detail row to hide sales records. That 'appears' to be is working fine.

When I've applied other hidden properties to group rows such as at the  AgentName level group is hides both rows of data for the agents that are on 2 teams.

If an agent has 2 rows of data one on each team, and one is 0.00 % - we need to hide the 0.00 % row but keep the row that has a valid % > 0.00.

This it the expression I'm using for the hidden 
=IIF(Fields!Category.Value = "Sales" , True, False)

Any help would be greatly appreciated....as I'm fairly new to SSRS and needing to deploy this report.

Thank you,
Cervello

Comment: Could you provide a picture example of the report? It would make it much easier to diagnose what you are trying to hide/not hide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to modify your expression a bit to account for = 0.00:

```
=iif(fields!Category.Value = "Sales" and fields!cancelpercent.value = cdec(0), true, false)
```